# Soll ich "wer" nach "dem" entsprechend deklinieren?

Tags: interrogative, relative-pronoun, declension

Meine Frage ist eigentlich ganz einfach: Soll man "Stehe zu dem, **wem** du liebst" oder "Stehe zu dem, **wen** du liebst" sagen?

Comment: _Zu dem_ bezieht sich auf eine spezifische Person. Korrekt ist _"Stehe zu dem, wen du liebst"_

Comment: Ich wüsste nicht, warum das eine schlechte Frage sein soll. Kongruenz von eingebetten Konstruktionen ist immer komplex.

Comment: Was mich erst mal verwirrt hatte, ist dass man sagt "Die Krone wurde - lass uns sagen - Wilhelm, **dem** Ersten, abgegeben. Deswegen hatte ich gedacht, dass man den Relativpronomen dem Verb im Hauptsatz entsprechend deklinieren sollte. Aber jetzt ist es mir klar, weil der Relativpronomen in einem gesonderten Satz steht, dass es unterschiedliche Fälle sind. Vielen Dank für die Erklärungen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Wo spielt eine Rolle, dass es um eine spezifische Person geht?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Stehe zu dem, <b>den</b> Du liebst."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Der Kopf einer solchen Konstruktion richtet sich nach der Funktion im eingebetteten Satz:

- *Stehe zu dem, der liebt*. (Subjekt im Nominativ)
- *Stehe zu dem, dessen Liebe du teilhaftig wurdest*. (Objekt im Genitiv)
- *Stehe zu dem, dem Liebe gegeben wird*. (Objekt im Dativ)
- *Stehe zu dem, den du liebst*. (Objekt im Akkusativ)
- *Stehe zu dem, dessen Liebe du bekommst*. (Genitivergänzung des Akkusativobjekts)
- *Stehe zu dem, dem scheint, niemand liebe ihn* ("Experiencer Subject" im Dativ)
- *Stehe zu dem, den nach Liebe dürstet* (Akkusativ; aber was das syntaktisch ist, ist schon eine separate Diskussion wert...)

Die gleiche Variante mit *wer* (als Indefinitpronomen) statt *der* klingt in meinen Ohren einfach immer seltsamer, hält sich aber an die gleichen Regeln.  Der Grund dafür wird wohl sein, dass semantisch das *der* im Nebensatz ein spezifisches Individuum bezeichnet (sozusagen eine freie Variable: *stehe zu allen X für die gilt: du liebst X*).

Comment: ... _den nach Liebe dürstet_: '_dürsten_' ist eines der wenigen Verben (dazu gehört auch '_frieren'_), die sich mit einem Akkusativ (_mich dürstet_), gelegentlich auch mit einem Dativ (_mir dürstet_) verbinden konnten, allerdings nur in archaischer Sprache, heute sagt man '_ich habe Durst_'.  Auch die Konstruktion '_ich dürste_' kommt vor, meist kombiniert mit '_nach_' im elegischen Sinne von '_sich verzehren nach, sich sehnen nach_'. Im letztem Beispiel ist das '_den_' syntaktisch Akkusativ'objekt', semantisch eher ein Akkusativ'subjekt' - das meinst du wohl mit 'separate Diskussion'.

Comment: Genau. "Friert" oder "dünkt" wären noch absurder gewesen in diesem Kontext...

Answer (score 3):

*Lieben* always takes the accusative case. The conjugation is independent of previous words. I would replace *wen* with *den* as it sounds more idiomatic

> Stehe zu dem, den du liebst.